# WSO2 GReg 5.1 Publisher does not have all the same functionalities as Management Console?

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I have installed WSO2 Governance Registry 5.1 and it is the very first time I am using it. I noticed that the Management Console shows me a message that states:

> From version 5.1.0 onwards, performing governance operations are
>   deprecated from the management console. Please use the publisher
>   app(https://localhost:9443/publisher) instead

When going to the Publisher link I can create for example a new WSDL, a new SOAPService or a new Enterprise Application.

But I cannot create a new Endpoint or a new Service as I can in the Management Console.

Also, I am not able to add more intricate relationships with Publisher as I can with Management. For example, in Management I can create a relationship of type "collaboratesWith". The management page gives me a free text to do that.

I can't create a "UsedBy" relationship in Publisher as well..

So, the question is: Is the Publisher Web Page still WIP and not all features are still there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, From WSO2 G-Reg 5.0.0 onward we have introduced the new Governance Center(GC) Hence we have moved all the governance related operations to GC.
2. Yes you can not create Endpoints manually from GC(publisher in this case) out of the box, To enable that follow below steps.

Find below files

> /GREG_HOME/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/extensions/app/greg_publisher/app.js:

and

> /GREG_HOME/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/extensions/app/greg_store/app.js:

Remove `'endpoint'` from `disabledAssets` list. Now restart G-Reg.

[image: List of endpoints]

3. You can create soap-services and rest-services manually. please find below screen shot(click on add button)

[image: ADD services manually]

4. Yes you can create custom associations. Please find this useful [blog post](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2016/03/how-wso2-governance-registry.html).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in the documentation, who would've thought.

> You can add custom association types in WSO2 G-Reg, and add them to
>   assets using the G-Reg Publisher. To create a new association type,
>   you can specify it to be available for default or specific asset types
>   by defining the new association type within the default, restservice,
>   and soapservice elements in the
>   /repository/conf/governance.xml file. Default association
>   type denotes all other asset types that are not overridden. The other
>   two association types(i.e restservice, and soapservice)denote the
>   overridden asset types, which are REST Services and SOAP Services. 
>   For an example, if you want to add a new association named criticalTo,
>   and make it available only for SOAP Services, modify the soapservice
>   association configuration as shown below. The values within the
>    tag are the comma-separated asset types that you can
>   associate using the criticalTo association type with a SOAP service.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance510/Adding+Associations+in+the+Publisher